# .npmrc gets ignored by maven plugin eirslett

Tags: maven, npm, gitlab

we have a gitlab pipeline which builds an angular app with maven

but after the command npm install it downloads the installation files from internet rather than from our registry(nexus)

```
[INFO] Installing node version v16.13.2
[INFO] Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v16.13.2/node-v16.13.2-linux-x64.tar.gz to /builds/fadak/sgs-project/.m2/repository/com/github/eirslett/node/16.13.2/node-16.13.2-linux-x64.tar.gz
[INFO] No proxies configured
[INFO] No proxy was configured, downloading directly
```

this is the log, can anyone help?

Comment: This does not seem to be the `npm install` command but the installation of node.js inside a docker container? Can that be the case?

Comment: you are correct

Comment: i derived that if it downloads the files from nodejs.org it will also download our node modules from the internet instead of nexus

Comment: No this seems to be the installation that needs fixing from somewhere else. Once it is installed it should still go install node modules from your nexus if your npmrc is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apparently you have to specify download root for eirslett and also you have to configure it so it inherits proxy config from maven like this:

```
<npmInheritsProxyConfigFromMaven>true</npmInheritsProxyConfigFromMaven>
                                    <nodeDownloadRoot>http://url/repository/npm-public/</nodeDownloadRoot>
                                    <npmDownloadRoot>http://url/repository/npm-public/</npmDownloadRoot>
```